# Finding AD group permissions source

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

We have an AD group as a Login in several servers, usually as sysadmin,
but I've found one server that this login has no access to any DB and has a server public role only.
I've talked to a member of this group about this issue,
and he told me that he has an access to this Server's DBs.
And endeed by opening SSMS as different user(using his AD credentials) at my local station,
he could select, update tables in this server, even shrinking a log file(but cannot see logins except sa and this group).
I cannot find a source for those permissions:
There is no Login\User with his credentials,
there are other AD groups, but if I revoke connect from this group then
he cannot longer connect to this server.
Public server role has only view any database permission
Public DB role has no permissions on dbo schema
Database is not in partial containment....
Where else can I search for a source of this Login's permissions?
*SQL Server 2012 on my and server's computers.

I used this query to fing this login

```
   USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @username sysname
DECLARE @objname sysname
DECLARE @found integer
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @results TABLE (Login sysname)

SET @username = ' '
WHILE @username IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SELECT @username = MIN(name)
FROM master.dbo.syslogins WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE sysadmin = 0
AND securityadmin = 0
AND serveradmin = 0
AND setupadmin = 0
AND processadmin = 0
AND diskadmin = 0
AND dbcreator = 0
AND bulkadmin = 0
AND name > @username
AND Name NOT LIKE N'NT %'
AND Name NOT LIKE N'##%'
-- this is the list of non system logins
-- ids in server roles may not have corresponding users
-- any database but they should not be removed
SET  @found = 0

IF @username IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    --  now we search through each non system database
    --  to see if this login has database access
    SET @objname = ''
    WHILE @objname IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @objname = MIN( name )
        FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE
        name > @objname
        AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name, 'status') = 'ONLINE'

        IF @objname IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = N'SELECT @found = COUNT(*) FROM [' + @objname
            + N'].dbo.sysusers s WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN master.dbo.syslogins x WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON s.sid = x.sid WHERE hasdbaccess = 1 AND x.name = '''+ @username + ''''
            EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@found Int OUTPUT',@found OUTPUT
            --SELECT @found, @objname, @username
            IF @found IS NOT NULL AND @found > 0
                SET @objname = 'zzzzz'  -- terminate as a corresponding user has been found
        END
    END

    IF @found = 0
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @results
    SELECT @username
    END
END
END

SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') ServerName ,Login
FROM @results r
ORDER BY Login
GO
```

Comment: Have you tried through "MSTSC" that is Remote Desktop login with your 'SA' or 'User' Login.

Comment: I don't understand what I'll acheive with that.
I don't need to RDP to this server, I can connect to this server with my local ssms
Also I'm a sysadmin so I don't need to use sa

Comment: Out of Nine "Server Role"  permission. If you have "sysadmin" permission then you have all permission of DB as well as Server. Have you check out your Server DB Permission.

Comment: For reference you check out here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx

Comment: Ok I've edited my question, I appreciate that you are trying to help but help like - check sysadmin role permission is not helpful, please read my question, I think that it is clear that I'm aware of what sysadmin role means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the source of those permissions:
This AD user had an "orphan" user in database with higher permissions than AD group.
So in order to connect to instance this user needs to be a part of the group
But after the connection he can get permissions directly from his "orphan" user in DBs
Even if the group that he is a part of is only public group
This group don't even have to have a corresponding user in database.
Hope I made myself clear because I wasn't familiar with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Login as the mystery user. Then run:

```
select * from sys.login_token
```

Somewhere in the output list will be token that grants you access. For instance you can try this (not guaranteed to work):

```
select * 
from sys.login_token lt
join sys.server_principals sp on sp.sid = lt.sid;
```

Comment: Yes it worked(actually I've been looking for this type of query didn't know this was possible - thanks!!) - it returns public server role and group role that I wrote, so nothing new there

Comment: So basically on this server the AD group that should grant sysadmin is missing from the SQL login token, right? What about at OS, from a command prompt on this problem machines run `whoami /all` or `whoami /groups`, see if the mystery AD group is present or not.

Comment: Not familiar with cmd on that level - actually no, the thing is that group exists on that server, but it has no real permissions(not that I could find) there, and still a member of that group can do dmls and shrink(examples), and I cannot find how is he able to do that

Comment: Is the entry in login_token marked as `GRANT OR DENY` or `DENY ONLY`?

Comment: an what about `select * from sys.fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'server')`, what does it list, when logged in as the trouble AD group member?

Comment: GRANT OR DENY - your query returns 3 rows one for public server role and two identical for this AD windows group - not sure if I was clear enough with my first comment

Comment: better post the output in your post.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Remus, I've found the answer, please check it if this is interesting to you.